# Go to error messages' `:help`

Tags: vimscript, help-system, error, message

How can I search the `help` entry for the last errors after the execution?

### Example

```
" try to run a command that doesn't exist
:qwerty
E492: Not an editor command: qwerty
```

I usually use `:echo errmsg`, `:messages` or `:Messages` (the latter is from [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) plugin and loads the original `messages` into the quickfix list). And then go to `:help E492` following this example.

Another option is `tabnew | put = execute('messages')`

I'm looking for a way to go directly to the `help` of the errors.

Comment: what is wrong with `:help E492` ?

Comment: I'm guessing if there is another way to do it, like "go to the last error" without having to type `:h [error number]`. Especially when there are a few errors, it would be nice to have each `help` page automatically opened

Comment: You can scan your messages for `E..` codes and try to open corresponding help topics then. However you will need to define what are the `last` errors then. And how to open it if there would be 20+ errors.

Comment: @MaximKim Yeah, the use case would be for ~4 errors. I'm learning Vimscript and find myself in this situation when running stuff, hence the question... I will try out your answer. BTW I use `habamax` everyday!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why direct `:help E...` is not an option, but you can create a command to open last error:

```
func! HelpLastErr()
    if empty(v:errmsg)
        return
    endif
    let errcode = matchstr(v:errmsg, '^E\d\+')
    if empty(errcode)
        return
    endif
    execute "help" errcode
endfunc
command! HelpLastErr call HelpLastErr()
```

[image: asciicast]

And if you need to open several help topics (4) you will need to parse output of `:messages` and manage to open several help windows (by default it always reuses existing help window).

Here is the quick and dirty solution (you can refactor it if needed):

```
func! HelpLastErrors(num)
    " get all messages into msgs using :redir
    redir => msgs
    :silent messages
    redir END

    if empty(msgs)
        return
    endif

    " collect errors into a hashtable to get rid of duplicates
    let errs = {}
    for msg in reverse(split(msgs, "\n"))
        let err = matchstr(msg, '^E\d\+')
        if !empty(err)
            let errs[err] = 1
        endif
    endfor

    " going over hash keys but also need to limit it to provided num
    let err_num = 1
    for err in keys(errs)
        " if we opened a help window already, split it, otherwise it would be
        " reused and only the last error would be shown
        if err_num > 1
            split
        endif
        " open help topic for the err
        execute "help" err
        " opened specified number of help windows? get out!
        if err_num == a:num
            return
        endif
        let err_num += 1
    endfor
endfunc

command! HelpLastErrors call HelpLastErrors(4)
```